# R H20 - Cross-validation with stratified sampling and non i.i.d. rows

Tags: r, cross-validation, h2o

I'm using H2O to analyse a dataset but I'm not sure how to correctly perform cross-validation on my dataset. I have an unbalanced dataset, so I would like to performed stratified cross-validation ( were the output variable is used to balance the groups on each partition).

However, on top of that, I also have an issue that many of my rows are repeats (a way of implementing weights without actually having weights). Independently of the source of this problem, I have seen before that, in some cases, you can do cross-validation were some rows have to be kept together. This seams to be the usage of fold_column. However, it is not possible to do both at the same time?

If there is no H2O solution, how can I compute the fold a priori and use it on H2O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [H2O-3 docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/fold_assignment.html) this can't be done:

> Note that all three options are only suitable for datasets that are i.i.d. If the dataset requires custom grouping to perform meaningful cross-validation, then a fold_column should be created and provided instead.

One quick idea is using `weights_column` instead of duplicating rows. Then both `balance_classes` and `weights_column` are available together as parameters in 
GBM, DRF, Deep Learning, GLM, Naïve-Bayes, and AutoML.

Otherwise, I suggest following workflow performed in R or H2O on your data to achieve both fold assignment and consistency of duplicates between folds:

1. take original dataset (no repeats in data yet)
2. divide it into 2 sets based on the outcome field (the one that is unbalanced): one for positive and one for negative (if it's multinomial then have as many sets as there are outcomes)
3. divide each set into N folds by assigning new `foldId` column in both sets independently: this accomplishes stratified folds
4. combine (`rbind`) both sets back together
5. apply row duplication process that implements weights (which will preserve your fold assignments automatically now).

Comment: Thanks. I did that using caret to produced a Fold Id column and it works fine. The problem now is that, in my tests, using fold_column in h2o makes the grid search much slower.

Comment: file a bug report about slow grid search when using fold column here https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV/issues